# How to correctly describe the size of the army using "strong"

Tags: numbers

How to say properly:
"They keep an army in Kashmir of the size of 30000 strong "

Or

"They have deployed an army 30000 strong"

Meaning it has 30000 soldiers? Do I need to put other words after strong?
Or it is just "x(number) strong"?

Like "they have a squad of the size of 30000 strong"?

Comment: When you say "30000 strong" that's a fairly precise measurement.  "An army of 30000 soldiers" would mean the same thing, in most cases.

Comment: It's [a declining usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thousand+strong%2Chundred+strong&year_start=1840&year_end=1980&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), and likely to sound weird if you don't use it *exactly* right. It's nearly always used as *[an army] of [so many] **hundred / thousand** strong* (*the size of 30000 strong* is not idiomatic).

Comment: This is right, but literary or archaic: *They have deployed an army 30000 strong.*

Comment: I think I would use "30,000 strong" only after naming the individual elements: "troops, 30,000 strong". The purpose of the phrase is to assign a number to some things mentioned.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - I don't agree. If you describe a group or organisation as "[number] strong", it means "consisting of [number] people".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - declining, maybe. _By the time we got to Woodstock/We were half a million strong_

Comment: _Queen's birthday honours: Angelina Jolie made dame in thousand-strong list_ (The Guardian, 2014)

Comment: _Meet Andorra's captain Ildefons Lima... and his SIX HUNDRED-strong collection of football shirts._ (BBC Sport)

Comment: ... after nearly two hours of Hebrew and Torah study in a warm classroom, the twenty-strong group around me (earnest university students and high-powered businesswomen and cool digital gurus, aged anywhere from 18 to 60) sing along energetically with a Hebrew number called Dayenu._ 'Why, aged 25, I’m converting to Judaism' The Times (London) 2019

Comment: So not 'archaic' really in British English.

Comment: I think this could be answered by a dictionary - the entry for '*strong adjective (IN NUMBER)*'  is pretty clear and gives examples

Comment: Note that the adjective comes directly after the numeral, not the noun. 'An army 30 000 strong' / 'a 30000-strong army'. The usage is similar but not identical to say  'a gate 2m high'  / 'a 3ft-wide door' . But as said above, old-fashioned.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I wouldn't call the usage archaic, but the Woodstock line is 50-year-old lyrics/poetry. My reason for urging caution to non-native speakers is it's not obvious why so many "credible" constructions simply won't work. *The protest marchers were dozens strong* simply won't wash!